Can a reverse-parabolic screen in the double-slit experiment test local vs. nonlocal interference formation?
Suppose that in a double-slit experiment, the slits open just in time for a photon to pass through, and a reverse-parabolic screen is used, with edges positioned much farther from the slits than the center. Could timing and path length differences reveal whether the interference pattern forms locally or nonlocally across the screen?
Imagine a photon passes through just after the slits open and hits near the center of the screen, with the edges far enough away that information about the slits opening hasn’t yet propagated there. But isn’t the probability of detecting the photon at the center calculated based on interference probabilities across the entire screen?
Could we assume the screen edges are distant enough that the precise timing of opening the slits just before the photon passes isn’t a major concern?
If this question isn’t fundamentally flawed, does it have a clear answer in physics, or could it serve as the basis for an experiment?

Could you repeat this thought experiment with an electron? I think to consider a photon just add unnecessary complexity. What would you expect to observe with one particle in the interferometer?

@Ruffolo imo opinion photon is simpler!

The odds of a photon hitting the center of the screen are independent of the edges of the screen. Also: there is no effect relating the timing of the slit being open and the screen edges (vs center). Either the photon gets through or it doesn’t. Note that opening/closing a slit to let a photon through involves a lot of practical difficulties, such that the information you hope to obtain is likely out of reach.

The DSE appears as a mystery for many, that's because they talk about the photon and totally neglect the EM field. It's like questioning about why a wave appears in the water but not stopping to think about the properties of the water itself that make the wave possible.  Water is elastic, energy can be stored and transmitted in this medium.
The EM field is very active, the double slit apparatus has an EM field, the photon is an EM field propagating disturbance (energy) in the field. The EM field of the apparatus will reveal its modes (allowable paths) when the photon arrives ... the paths can be calculated with Feynman's path integral .... paths that are most probable are ones that have lengths of integer multiples of the wavelength .... the EM field of the apparatus is resonant (just like a laser cavity).
As you open your slits ... you need to open them at the speed c (which is impossible)... the EM field of the apparatus will react at the speed c ... modes will develop at speed c and photons will be guided at speed c. The photons are dumb, the EM field does all the work!
In general the DSE is taught in high school with a 1930s textbook based on Huygens from the 1700s ... it leads to a lot of questions ... the QM era (Dirac, Feynman) added some clarity ... but there are much more important things in physics now than the DSE .... focus on those.

This does not answer the question, and is not generally accurate.

@DrChinese Yes but based on your past answers here on PSE you are biased towards the textbook/academic/established answers ....  for you there is only the photon, the EM field of the apparatus/universe seems unimportant.  That helps to perpetuate the great mystery ....

Guilty as charged :)  I am biased towards generally accepted science - such as that found in textbooks and academic research papers.  Anything that does not fit that description should, at a minimum, be labeled as non-standard. If it is an unpublished personal theory, I don't believe it should be presented on PSE at all.

@DrChinese Yes but if look at the 5% to 10% of academic papers that avoid the established ideas from 1930 QM you can get insights that make a hell of a lot of common sense.  The established ideas force you to believe there is a great mystery.  In any case I've always found your answers very thorough and well based (maybe too well based).
